# How to add refresh token expiration date to token endpoint response?

Tags: identityserver4

I need to have refresh token expiration date on client side.
By default Identity Server returns access token expiration date in response.
I can make a request with expired refresh token and handle not authorized response by requesting user to login again, but it's another round trip which can be skipped if I have refresh token expiration date on client side.In this case we can check refresh token on client side and if it's expired then user will be redirected to login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general scenario you just don't need it. Look: once your access token expires, you get a new **pair** where the fresh refresh token is valid for a month again (the default value, you are free to enlarge it even more). And so on and so on. So the *another round trip* occurs when your app has not been used for a really long-long time. And most likely that's not so bad.

But if you still like to customize the response, it's [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56330812/1426685).

In your case there will be something like:

```cs
public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
{
    var ttl = context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Client.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime;
    context.Result.CustomResponse = 
        new Dictionary<string, object>{{"refresh_interval", ttl}};
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is compare the expiration time(convert it to universal time) with current time and you'll come to know the refresh token is expired or not, no need to make another call for finding it out.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have refresh token expiration date on client side. The question is how to get that expiration date from Identity Server.